# How to test a method which takes a callable as argument with PhpUnit and Prophecy

Tags: php, promise, phpunit, guzzle, prophecy

I'm using Guzzle's asynchronous request and have them implemented in a service that I would like to test now.

My method looks like this (pseudo, so if it's not 100% valid, please excuse)

```
public function getPlayer(string $uiid, array &$player = [])
{
    $options['query'] = ['id' => $uiid];

    $promise = $this->requestAsync('GET', $this->endpoint, $options);
    $promise->then(function (ResponseInterface $response) use (&$player) {
        $player = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    });

    return $players;
}
```

Now I want to test it, but I don't really know how to mock the callable, because I'm always getting the error

`1) tzfrs\PlayerBundle\Tests\Api\Player\PlayerServiceTest::testGetPlayer
Prophecy\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Expected callable or instance of PromiseInterface, but got object.`

This is how I have it implemented currently

```
/** @var ObjectProphecy|PromiseInterface $response */
$promise = $this->prophesize(PromiseInterface::class);

$promise->then()->will($this->returnCallback(function (ResponseInterface $response) use (&$player){}));
```

Didn't work. And this

`$this->returnCallback(function (ResponseInterface $response) use (&$player){})`

didn't work either. Same error. And when simply trying a dummy callback

`$promise->then(function(){});`

I get the error `Error: Call to a member function then() on string`, even after `->reveal()`ing the promise first. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had another idea.

Make a dependency that will make what you make now in `requestAsync()`;
And then create it's mock that will return another mock of promise.

```
class PromiseMock
{
    private $response;

    public function __construct(ResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $this->response = $response;
    }

    public function then($callable)
    {
        $callable($this->response);
    }
}
```

test looks like

```
public function testGetPlayer()
{
    $response = new Response(200, [], "Your test response");
    $promiseMock = new PromiseMock($response);

    $mockDependency = $this->getMockBuilder('YourDependencyClass')
                ->getMock()
                ->expects("requestAsync")->willReturn($promiseMock);

    $service = new YouServiceClass($mockDependency);

    $service->getPlayer("76245914-d56d-4bac-8419-9e409f43e777");
}
```

And in your class changes only

```
$promise = $this->someNameService->requestAsync('GET', $this->endpoint, $options);
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your answer. I like this one better, but it would still modify the code too much and the `then` function seems like a polyfill just to make the test work. :/. Is there just no way to mock a callable directly without creating another class?

Comment: But that's what mocks do, in general. And I don't think there is another way.

Comment: Sorry, I'm an Idiot. I didn't see it's a `PromiseMock`. I thought it was still the `Processor`. I'll try it out

Comment: Hey. Sorry that I have wasted your time, because you wouldn't be able to solve my problem. My mistake was hidden in a line I didn't show you here...My client which called the `requestAsync` in the Test had `willReturn(PromiseInterface::class)`. So it was a string. And therefore the error message was correct. I fixed it... Sorry!

Comment: Ok, no problem.

Comment: I upvoted you though, maybe someone else has the problem you answered.

Answer (score 1):

I would inject a processor to your class and call it's callable. Check it out, the rest is quite obvious:

```
public function __construct(Processor $processor) {
    $this->processor = $processor;
}

public function getPlayer(string $uiid, array &$player = [])
{
    $options['query'] = ['id' => $uiid];

    $promise = $this->requestAsync('GET', $this->endpoint, $options);
    $promise->then([$this->processor, "processResponse"]);

    $player = $this->processor->getPlayer();

    return $players;
}
```

And processor:

```
class Processor {

    private $player;        

    public function processResponse (ResponseInterface $response) {
        $this->player = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    }

    public function getPlayer() { return $this->player;}
}
```

Comment: This looks like I would have to create a new class simply for testing my Service, right? I wouldn't want to do that, changing my project just so a test would work. Isn't there a different way to mock the callable somehow?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. It would create a new class to follow SOLID principle (which is one of key principle of Lavarel) - single responsibility. Your current implementation supposes you make two functions by one class - to send and to parse response.  And as one of bonuses of using SOLID you will get a testable code.

Comment: Valid point. Not using Laravel though, but Symfony. And another thing is, that I have split Reading and Writing already. The reading happens somewhere else, but I thought I should put it together, since it doesn't really change functionality for a stackoverflow question. 

But, if I implement it like you, calling a method via array instead of a callable, how is that affecting/changing my tests? I would still have to mock the `then` function in which I had to pass a callback - Edit: I'll have to go for aprox. 1 hour. So if you answer, I will answer later

Comment: Just to clarify if there's a misunderstanding: I'm not asking for code improvement, but on how to mock the `->then()` method with Prophecy.

Comment: Apparently, we have a lunch at the same time. And during the lunch, I had another idea. Still needs some refactoring, but maybe, closer to what you want to get